# how to make my user form insert data to the next row

Tags: vba, excel

my user form keep overwrite the same row  every time i enter new date in the form.i want the data to be inserted in the row("A6") so forth and so on. The code i'm using to write date in the sheet.

```
Private Sub Commandok_Click()
Dim RowCount As Long

RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Offset(5).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
' Write data to worksheet
    With Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")
     .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.task_done.Value
     .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.task_name.Value
     .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = DateValue(Me.task_date.Value)
     .Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.task_note.Value
     .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = Me.task_additional.Value
End With

End Sub
```

[image: Current screenshot]

Comment: What row does the region containing cell A6 start on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Simply use this to get the last row:

```
RowCount =  Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" &  Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: it's not working , it keeps writing on the same cell even with your adjustment .

Comment: @ObedLorisson - Which row does the region that contains cell A6 start on?  If you don't know, type `?Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Offset(5).CurrentRegion.Address` in the Immediate Window and tell us what range it shows.

Comment: @ObedLorisson Also, do you want the new row written below the current region, or do you just want to replace what is in the row containing the first blank in column "A"?

Comment: @YowE3K yes i want everyt subsequent entry to be written in the row below the previous one

Comment: I did a quick update to your answer so that it correctly qualified the `Range` and `Rows` references.  (Then +1'd the answer)  Revert the change back if you don't agree with it.

Comment: I saw that after I posted, was going to add it in comment. Thanks for the +1. Appreciate that.

Comment: I don't like the rest of the OP's code, which is why I posted my own answer - but your answer certainly would fix the issue raised in the question, and does it with the minimum amount of change to the original code (which is always a bonus).

Comment: i'm a newbie with vba but both answers , try both ways doesn't write the data where i need it to be . and it's not working .Just to be fair some column have a formula in them . i don't know if that will make a difference

Comment: Of course it makes a difference. This assignment actually finds the last empty cell's row number. So if you have formula in your empty looking cells, these cells are considered as non blank cells. You can try and see that both YowE3K's method and my correction do what you need if you remove your formulas from empty looking cells.

Comment: Sorry I get it wrong. If the formula is somewhere else, it is ok. It doesn't change what you are trying to do based on your code.

Comment: I just fix the prob ,was with the merged cell from A1 to A5. for some reasons it was not able to insert the data .

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your screenshot (rather than by what is implied by your current code), I think you want:

```
Private Sub Commandok_Click()
    Dim NewRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        NewRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ' Write data to worksheet
        .Cells(NewRow, "A").Value = Me.task_done.Value
        .Cells(NewRow, "B").Value = Me.task_name.Value
        .Cells(NewRow, "C").Value = DateValue(Me.task_date.Value)
        .Cells(NewRow, "F").Value = Me.task_note.Value
        .Cells(NewRow, "G").Value = Me.task_additional.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

It's usually a bad idea to use `CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` to work out where to write to, because that will confuse you if your `CurrentRegion` doesn't start at row 1 and, in your particular case, `CurrentRegion` looks like it extends quite a long way down the sheet so that your `RowCount` was probably a largish number.